# Bash 'type someCmd' : what means 'hashed'? (different outputs for 'type mkdir')

Tags: bash, shell, types, mkdir, scite

What puzzles me is, that I am getting different output running this two-liner script:

```
help | head -n1
type mkdir
```

from within SciTE (here the SciTE output panel output):

```
GNU bash, version 4.3.46(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
mkdir is /bin/mkdir
```

and from within a Terminal window (here the Terminal output):

```
GNU bash, version 4.3.46(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
mkdir is hashed (/bin/mkdir)
```

How does it come that the same script executed by the same shell gives not the same output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is situational:

**The first time `bash` executes an *external utility* in a given session *by filename only* (whether successfully or not), it remembers its full path for faster re-execution later** (saving the need to look for the utility in all directories listed in the `$PATH` variable *again*).

**This remembering (caching) is called *hashing*** and happens implicitly via builtin `hash`.

Therefore, **before `mkdir` is ever *executed* in a given session**, `type mkdir` returns:

```
mkdir is /bin/mkdir
```

**After having executed `mkdir` at least once**, `type mkdir` then reports:

```
mkdir is hashed (/bin/mkdir)
```

You can tell `bash` to "forget" all remembered paths with `hash -r`, or selectively with `hash -d <name>`; just `hash` prints all currently hashed paths and their hit counts - see `help hash`.